# Python list comprehension with objects

Tags: python, list, variables, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a list of the following form

```
a = [group[0],
     group[1],
     group[2]]
```

When using list comprehension or know this method

```
a = ['group[{}]'.format(i) for i in range(3)]
a = ['group[0]',
     'group[1]',
     'group[2]']
```

So what I get is a string but I need the variable.

Just to add some more background info. I am using Ansys SpaceClaim which have a scripting function to create geometry. When I select bodies I get the following

```
# Merge Bodies
no_bodies = GetRootPart().Components[0].Components.Count

targets = BodySelection.Create([GetRootPart().Components[0].Components[0].Content.Bodies[0],
GetRootPart().Components[0].Components[1].Content.Bodies[0],
GetRootPart().Components[0].Components[2].Content.Bodies[0],
GetRootPart().Bodies[0]])
result = Combine.Merge(targets, Info1)
```

So i would like to substitute that with somehing like

```
    targets = BodySelection.Create([GetRootPart().Components[0].Components[i].Content.Bodies[0] for i in range(3)])
```

btw I can see I am also missing the last bodie

Comment: `a = [group[0], group[1], group[2]]` is just `a = group[0:3]`

Comment: Yes, I have not been clear to begin with. I have modified the question so it shows the code used. As you see it is group[0].body[0], group[1].body[0] etc

Comment: I have also edited my answer, should work with a comprehension and adding the two lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to iterate over a certain range:

```py
BodySelection.Create([
    GetRootPart().Components[0].Components[i].Content.Bodies[0]
    for i in range(3)
])
```

After your edit:

```py
# Merge Bodies
no_bodies = GetRootPart().Components[0].Components.Count

targets = BodySelection.Create(
    [
        GetRootPart().Components[0].Components[i].Content.Bodies[0]
        for i in range(3)
    ]
    + [GetRootPart().Bodies[0]]
)
result = Combine.Merge(targets, Info1)
```

Comment: thankyou I thought I tried that of the first thing apparently I did not. Because it is working :)